# BottomSheet is collapsed after return from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a weird problem with `BottomSheetBehavior` and Jetpack Navigation. I use Jetpack Navigation to navigate between fragments.

I have a detail fragment, which there is a ConstraintLayout as the BottomSheetBehavior.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/modal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_bg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="350dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
    ....
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And on the fragment file, I set the BottomSheetBehavior to STATE_HIDDEN, so every time I open the detail, the Bottom sheet won't show yet.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController)

    modal.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN

    ....

    modalButton.setOnClickListener {
        modal.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
    }
}
```

Also there is a listener to modal button, which when clicked will show the bottom sheet with Collapsed state. It works, but not 100%.

The problem occurs when I navigate from my detail fragment to another fragment and then come back to detail (onViewCreated will be called again), the bottom state is showing with a collapsed state* which should not be.

```
navController.navigate(R.id.xyz_fragment)
```

So, I added bottom sheet callback to see if the callback is called. But the callback is not called.

```
modal.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onStateChanged: $newState")
        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            // do nothing
        }
    })
```

And, I tried to hide the bottom sheet, then press the modal button again. But, the bottom sheet won't show anymore, no matter how many times I press the button.

Please help me! Thanks!